# TFS Build Server upgrade from 2008 to 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

We installed Team Foundation Build Server 2012 on a server which had Team Foundation Build Server 2008. When we are trying to queue our new builds, they are returning the following error message:

[image]

We are using Upgrade Template as Process file and have tried creating new builds and also the existing builds and thy are all returning the same error.

We have also run the commands to repair defined in the workaround in the following website but it's still returning the same error:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765469/build-fails-with-error-on-createworkspacetask-and-missing-parameter-buildagenturi

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the above issue by copyying BuildAgentUri property in the Build Targets file and then it worked. More explaination is available at the following URL:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/389da76d-4637-4556-a68f-bafb9febc8ea/how-to-troubleshoot-trror-in-ant-build-with-tfs-2012?forum=tee